# Pandas dataframe select value from array

Tags: arrays, pandas, select

I have a pandas data frame that looks like the image below. I would like to select all data frame rows that contain a specific value in routes field (4008182). I have tried something like df['routes'].isin([4008182]) but it does not work. Any suggestions? Thank you
[image]

Comment: Looks like `routes` is a columns of lists.  You could try `[4008182 in r for r in df.Routes]`, and index with that, but it will be slow.  I'd recommend a relationship relationship DataFrame that relates routes to whatever this table is, so you can do much quicker lookup

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pandas.Series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), this code should do the trick:

```
df[df.routes.str.contains('4008182')]
```

**EDIT:**

Considering that the routes column is a list of numbers, the solution below is complemented using apply/lambda:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: 4008182 in x['routes'], axis=1)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work because routes field does not contain a string but a list of numbers.Thanks

Comment: Hi @GiovanniZambotti, I have just edited the answer to consider this situation. Please let me know if it worked as you expect.

Comment: This works df[df.apply(lambda x: '4008182' in x['routes'], axis=1)], so this means that it is not a number list

Comment: I'm glad to know that it helped you in some way. Please accept and upvote my answer if you think it deserves.